# How to cancel request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, cancellation

I have function:

```
$scope.openNode = function (user) {

  var req = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/user/',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  $http(req).then(function (response) {
    //smth do
  }, function () {

  });

};
```

I press the button this function is activated. If I poke again, then the request is repeated. How do I make the previous request canceled or ignored?

Comment: Why are you making a GET request with a Content-Type? GET requests don't have a body; there is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: Think you meant to write: `accept: 'application/json'`

Comment: Yes/ 
In this case it does not matter